# Users with German locale are not able to find entries with number, which contains two dots in it - e.g. 82.3189.37

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

Users with German locale are not able to find entries with number, which contains two dots in it - e.g. "82.3189.37" (actually, Latvian locale does the same trick). When users with English locale are searching for the same number, they are able to find the corresponding entry.

I assume, that it is because dots are used to separate thousands in German language - e.g. 1.000.500,50 Eur.

There could be a workaround for users with German locale, but it doesn't work for users with English locale (see table below).

- 82.3189.37 - **German**: no results - **English**: one entry found
- 82.3189* - **German**: one entry found - **English**: no results
- 82.3189.* - **German**: one entry found - **English**: no results
- 82.3189 37 - **German**: one entry found - **English**: no results

One more possible workaround could be to set English for "My Content and Search Languages" of "Language and Region" settings in user profiles, **but maybe there is a better solution?**

Best regards,
Aleks

Answer (score 0):

At this moment we didn't find better solution to just add English to **My Content and Search Languages** of user profile settings.

Users can do it by themselves as well (in SP 2013 on-premises):

About Me > editing your profile > ... > Language and Region > expand Show Advanced language Settings > add English to **My Content and Search Languages** > Save all and close

Please note, that it could take up to one hour to changes take effect (depending on how timer job is configured).